# How to make a stretchable header view collection view [Swift]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

In my swift app I've a collection view and I want to creare a stretchable header view like this in table view: https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/how-to-create-a-stretchable-tableviewheader-in-ios-ee9ed049aba3

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will get more help more quickly if you attempt to solve your problem yourself and post questions that arise when you encounter difficulties. In this case, I can't see why the approach described for a tableview won't work just as well in a collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question yourself with that article link, unless I miss something.

I will copy & paste for you and others that may have the same question, if it helps, because it even ships with a github link (kudos to [Abhimuralidharan](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan) @ Medium):

> Create a tableview with the basic datasource and delegate methods which are required to simply load the table with some data.
>
> Set the tableview’s contentInset property:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(300, 0, 0, 0)
```

> Here, I set the top value as 300 which is a calculated number which I will set as the initial normal height for the header imageview. Now, that we set the contentInset , the tableview’s frame will start at (0,0) and the first cell will start at (0,300).
>
> Now, create an imageview with height 300 and add it to the current View above the tableview.

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: “poster”)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

> Then, add the following code in the scrollview delegate method scrollViewDidScroll which gets called every time the tableview is scrolled.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll (_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = 300 — (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
    let height = min(max(y, 60), 400)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height)
}
```

> Compile and run the code. Full source code is available in [github](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/StretchableTableViewHeader-Swift).

Comment: thank you very much but I meant collection view not table view.